# Finding a Pakistani case from 1955

Tags: constitutional-law, pakistan

Does anyone know where online I can find a coyp of the law report of *Federation of Pakistan v. Maulvi Tamizuddin Khan* 1955 PLD 240? It's mentioned on Wikipedia [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Federation_of_Pakistan_v._Maulvi_Tamizuddin_Khan)

Answer (score 1):

I cannot find an actual law report, presumably due to the age of the judgement, but [this](http://www.cssforum.com.pk/css-optional-subjects/group-vi/constitutional-law/44332-federation-pakistan-vs-maulvi-tamizuddin.html) from the Civil Service of Pakistan seems to be one of the better summaries.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://pakistanlaw.pk/case_judgements/176696/federation-of-pakistan-versus-maulvi-tamizuddin), at the moment, also [here](http://www.cssforum.com.pk/css-optional-subjects/group-vi/constitutional-law/44332-federation-pakistan-vs-maulvi-tamizuddin.html). The documents are not identical, and it is likely that there is no online official version (it is not on the [court's web page](https://www.supremecourt.gov.pk/) AFAICT)